# flutter:: How do I delete files stored in a directory?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a function that can delete voice files stored in a directory.
The code below is the delete function I created.

```
  _delete() {
    //audioPlayer.delete();
    print(widget.index);
    Directory appDirec =
    Directory(widget.file.elementAt(widget.index));
    appDirec.delete(recursive: true);
    print(appDirec);
    setState(() {
      position = new Duration();
      widget.file.remove(widget.file.elementAt(widget.index));
      _icon = Icons.delete;
      _color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
    });
  }
```

But when I run it, I get an error

> The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture: type
> '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String'

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the directory, access the file like following

```
try {
      final file = await File('$appDirec/audiofile.mp3');

      await file.delete();
    } catch (e) {
      return 0;
    }
```